# Linux: bin file not found when executed using a symbolic link in another folder

Tags: linux, command, hyperlink, bin

In Linux, I have a **symbolic link** to a .bin file in:

```
~/bin>
```

So, I have:

```
~/bin>l

lrwxrwxrwx  1 myuser mymachine    56 Sep 27 09:25 Myfile.bin -> ./otherFolder/Myfile.bin
```

If I execute this .bin in the "bin" folder, there is no problem:

```
~/bin>Myfile.bin
```

But if I execute it from another folder:

```
~/other>../bin/Myfile.bin
```

the result is:

```
-bash: /home/myuser/bin/Myfile.bin: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your *symlink* is broken.

What is the output of

```
cd ~/bin
file ./otherFolder/Myfile.bin
```

?

**edit**

If you do :

```
~/bin>Myfile.bin
```

you run Myfile.bin from PATH, and it's not necessary ~/bin, depends of your $PATH variable.

Comment: You´re right! my symbolic link was broken (I have use the file command to know it). I´d have to put './otherFolder/Myfile.bin' instead of './otherFolder/Myfile.bin' when I create the symbolic link.